# Misplaced clauses

Tags: grammar

> However, most assets are still subject to some price volatility and inflation, even those considered a strong store of value, such as gold.

Is ”even those considered a strong store of value” a misplaced clause? Or is the sentence wrong for some other reason?

Comment: Why do you think it is misplaced ?

Comment: @NigelJ Somebody told me it was, but I could not see why.

Comment: I think you are close @EdwinAshworth. Please make your comment to an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: Sorry; I've close-voted as a duplicate and would consider that deleterious to the site's professionalism and thus credibility.